# Using variables in MySQL UPDATE - (PHP/MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to use variables in mysql update code, but i got the else {echo error message}.

```
$overwriteName = "UPDATE name SET name = '{$steamprofile['personaname']}' WHERE steamid = '{$steamprofile['steamid']}';"; 
            
            if ($db->query($overwriteName) === TRUE) {
                echo "success";
            } else {
                echo "error";

            }
```

Comment: Get the actual errormessage. How to do that depends which API you're using, mysqli or PDO.

Comment: You're already using an API that supports **prepared statements** with bounded variable input, you should utilize parameterized queries with placeholders (prepared statements) to protect your database against [SQL-injection](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/)!
 Get started with [`mysqli::prepare()`](http://php.net/mysqli.prepare) for MySQLi and  [`PDO::prepare()`](http://php.net/pdo.prepare) for PDO

Comment: i am using mysqli

Comment: Change `echo "error";` to `echo 'Error: ' . $db->error;`

Answer (score 1):

An easy way of doing this is using [prepared statement](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp):
(it's also more secure than using query, see the link for more information)

```
if($stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE name SET name = ? WHERE steamid = ?')){ // prepare the query
   $stmt->bind_param('ss',$steamprofile['personaname'],$steamprofile['steamid']); // bind your parameters (as many s as there are variables)
   $stmt->execute();
   // then your code 
}
```

Comment: @EnelGy I forgot a parenthesis, can you tell me the error?

Comment: i know, i have already add that parenthesis but i mean it give me                if ($db->query($overwriteName) === TRUE) {
                echo "success";
            } else {
                echo "error";

            }          <---------- echo "error";

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with your sql connection or table

Answer (score -1):

PHP doesn't substitute the value of a variable if you enclose it between simple quotes `'$variable'`.

In the query declaration, enclose `$steamprofile['personaname']` and `$steamprofile['steamid']` like this:

`$overwriteName = "UPDATE name SET name = " . "$steamprofile['personaname']" . " WHERE steamid = " . "$steamprofile['steamid']" . ";";`

Or don't enclose them at all:

`$overwriteName = "UPDATE name SET name = " . $steamprofile['personaname'] . " WHERE steamid = " . $steamprofile['steamid'] . ";";`